# Major Burns looked Major Houlihan squarely in the eye

Tags: grammar

> Major Burns looked Major Houlihan squarely in the eye. (from military English)

I feel the verb 'looked' generally needs prepositions like 'for', 'at', or 'after' before objects.

The example sentence has preposition 'in' and object 'the eye' but also another person object Houlihan right after the verb 'looked'.

Though I understand the sentence, this type of usage of 'look' is rare to me.

Question: grammarly wrong but idiomatic?

Answer (score 4):

Transitive uses of "Look" are mostly now obselete, or limited in use.  This is an idiomatic use

> Look (someone) in the eye/face.

It can be be modified by adverbs like "squarely" but you can't say "He looked the dog in the tail".  It is mostly limited to eyes and faces.

It has the implication of making eye-to-eye contact, particularly as a way of demonstrating (brutal) honesty.

Not particularly "military"  (and your quote comes from a script or novel of the Film/TV show M*A*S*H) Burns is having a secret affair with Houlihan.